# Autofac Owned<>

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I don't quite understand the difference between Autofac Owned and not Owned disposable components.

```
interface IMessageHandler
{
    void Handle(Message message);
}

class MessagePump
{
    Func<Owned<IMessageHandler>> _handlerFactory;

    public MessagePump(Func<Owned<IMessageHandler>> handlerFactory)
    {
        _handlerFactory = handlerFactory;
    }

    public void Go()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var message = NextMessage();

            using (var handler = _handlerFactory())
            {
                handler.Value.Handle(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What would be difference between the above code to the following:

```
class MessagePump
{
    IMessageHandler _handler;
    
    public MessagePump(IMessageHandler handler)
    {
        _handler = handler;
    }
    
    public void Go()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var message = NextMessage();
    
            _handler.Handle(message);
        }
    }
}
```

They are both disposed manually when I choose, what is the difference then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Owned<T>` informs Autofac you do not want Autofac to dispose your dependency, beacuse you are going to do it by yourself. Then - you can/should use `using` statement or call `Dispose()` directly in your code to dispose the dependency, `Dispose()` would not be called automatically.

When you are not going to use `Owned<T>` dependency, you do not dispose your dependencies by yourself - Autofac would do it for you, when necessary. You do not have to use `using` statement, you do not have to remember whether the dependency is disposable or not.

Comment: There is an additional feature: when using Owned you can also use PerOwned lifestyle for dependencies of Owned service. That's means reusing dependency instance under Owned root - similar to assigning it to variable and using the variable instead of creating each time.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that if you don't use Owned, you will not create a nested lifetime scope for T *and its dependencies*. If you dispose your instance manually, you will not have disposed any dependencies that were registered as `InstancePerLifetimeScope` as they now live on the same lifetime scope as your MessagePump.

For instance, if your handlers depend on database resources themselves, the general idea is you want those to live along with your handler, not with the message pump that I believe is long-lived.